# How can open the Excel file contains a form without hide other open files?

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel file with VBA Userform when I open file, my code hide all open files and shows userform.
I want when VBA file opens just hide the file coded and set all other open files show

I use this code in VBA - `ThisWorkbook`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
ActiveWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
```

To

```
Windows("Test.xls").Visible = False 'Your workbook name
```

Comment: its work but i can't enter data into other excel file opened or with my project VBA because my Sheets not visible when i use first code i can enter my data into userform

Comment: Are you sure because I can change the other opened sheets? I think your userform is `Modal` and that's why you are not able to do any change. Make it `Modeless` and you would be able to change.

Comment: yes i'm sure and my code in ThisWorkbook is
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
SaveSetting "GUA", "BEL", "EDDIS", Range("A1").Text
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Workbooks.Application.Quit
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveWorkbook.Application.ShowStartupDialog = False
ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows("BM Branches.xls").Visible = False 'Your workbook name
'ActiveWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
BrForm2.Show

End Sub

Comment: Set `ShowModal` property to `False` or change the `.Show` to `BrForm2.Show vbModeless` and then check